# Excel 2016 Chart > Date and Text on the same Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, formatting

I received an interesting question yesterday during at work. Is it possible to have Date and Text values on the same Axis in Excel Chart, but that this "text" is actually formatted or somehow transformed into date value?!

Here are the Pictures what is actually asked:

This is a small table (dummy example) of data on how it should look, butas you can see, it is a mix of date/text values. And you can't manually adjust bounds, minimum and maximum date values as it is on the second picture.
[image: Data Table]

[image: Axis format without Bounds]

What I actually wish to know is if  it possible to get this date bounds as you can see on the third picture, but having also text values inside? I put December 2019 and May 2020 just as an example, but instead of first and last date value, I would like to have some text, like Start/End. 
These bounds on the right side (red marked), are only possible when my values are Date! I understand that, but is there a way to change values somehow , using custom format or some formula to help in this case to have this "Start/End undercover" with Date values or something?

[image: Axis with Bounds]

Comment: In my opinion, it is not possible to partly change the Date values on X-axis to be non-date text and keep settings for bounds. Maybe it is a stupid approach, entering the text you need into two text boxes, set them with no outline, cover first and last date value and group them with chart.

Answer (score 0):

Put your labels ("Start" and "End" plus dates) above the numeric values, and insert your chart. If you have any non-dates in the first row, Excel will ignore the actual dates and treat everything like a plain text label.

Bonus: put series names to the left of each row of numeric values, and they'll appear in the legend instead of "Series 1" and "Series 2".

[image]

Comment: Thank you! BUT, what I actually wanted is exactly what you wrote: "...Excel will ignore the actual dates and treat everything like a plain text label." 
Is there a way to have text and treated as a date?

Comment: How would you expect Excel to interpret "Start" and "End" as dates? And how would you expect it to look different from the chart I posted?